# Track custom parameters for click events in GA4

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-4

We've recently upgraded to GA4 and previously tracked our events using the following code:

```
ga('send', { hitType: 'event', eventAction: 'test_cameron', eventCategory: document.title });
```

As part of the upgrade this code now looks like:

```
gtag('event', 'test_cameron', { event_category: document.title });
```

And we are able to see this new custom event in the same list as the standard events that GA4 tracks such as clicks, page_views, etc:

[image]

However we're concerned that this approach could make this list become a bit overwhelming as we have about 100+ custom events which are all essentially clicks but we want to know which particular click was actioned using our custom name.

Ideally we'd be able to store all these events under the main click event and then filter down the clicks by those custom names... but its not clear if this is possible in GA4 or how to do it... we don't want to have to manually set them all up in GA4 itself and would prefer to be able to pass additional params to the standard click event.

We thought perhaps doing:

```
gtag('event', 'click', { event_label: 'test_cameron', event_category: document.title });
```

And then we'd be able to view the clicks using that `event_label`.

But we've not seen anywhere in the GA4 UI under the events where we can see these labels. **Or more concerning will this cause GA4 to track both the automatic click tracking and then also our custom click code and cause our data to be doubled up for clicks...** Is doing the custom event as we were originally doing the correct way to track specific clicks?